# The condition for preserving the convexity?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Given function $u: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, construct the following set $$Z \equiv \left\{ u(x_2,y) - u(x_1,y) \mid y \in Y \right\}$$

---

The question is the condition under which the convexity is preserved. That is, suppose $Y$ is convex, what kind of $u$ can ensure $Z$ is also convex. An easy condition is $u$ being linear in $y$. I was wondering whether there are any other conditions.

Comment: What are $X,Y,Z$? Please provide more details.

Comment: @almosteverywhere Sorry about the confusion. $Z$ is defined based on $X$, $Y$, and $u$. My initial thought was that $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of Euclidean space, and $u$ is continuous. But maybe it can be more general. In other words, the "condition" in the title also involves the space $X$, $Y$, and $u$ belong to.

Comment: Are $x_2,x_1$ fixed?

Comment: @almosteverywhere Yes, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are fixed for a specific $Z$. But they are arbitrary within $X$.